# Let $M \sim \operatorname{Geometric}(p)$ and $ X \vert M = m \sim $ Uniform discrete on {1,m}

Tags: probability, density-function

Let $M \sim  \operatorname{Geometric}(p)$ and $ X \vert M = m \sim $ Uniform discrete on {1,m}.

I want to find the density of X and then estimate the value of $p$ knowing one sample $X = x$.

If the density were continuous, I would do something like this:

$$ f_X = \int_{\text{over m}} f_M *f_{X \mid M = m}\,dm $$

However the densities are discrete so instead of the integral I have a summation.

This is what I found:
$$ f_X(k) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m} p(1-p)^{m-1}\enspace (1<k<m)$$

First of all  I am not so sure this is ok, so can someone check this result?

Then, how could I estimate the value of $p$ knowing the value of an output $x$?

Comment: You would need to have a prior distribution for $p$ to be able to get the distribution of $p$ given an output $x$ (if you had a prior you could use Bayes' Theorem to get the conditional distribution of $p$).

Comment: Why density? Assuming mass points of $M$ start at $1$, the probability mass function is $P(X=k)=\sum\limits_{m=k}^\infty P(X=k\mid M=m)P(M=m)$ for $k=1,2,\ldots$ by total probability.

Comment: Why m starts equal to k? How would you write explicitly the density?